Load List of Movies Using useReducer hook
I am learning react.js, and I am on a way learning react hooks.
I followed some examples on 'useReducer' where I have a search input for searching movies, and I load the list of movies from API.
The code is as follows.
The MovieSearch.jsx;
'use strict';
import React, {useReducer, Fragment} from "react";
import MovieAPI from "./movieAPI";
import Spinner from "./Spinner.jsx";


export default function MovieSearch(){

    const initialObjectVal = {
        "movieQuery" : "",
        "movieList" : []        
    };

    const createMovieListComponent = (movielist, isLoading) => {
        if(isLoading == true){
            return <Spinner />;
        }
        return (isLoading === false && movielist !== undefined && movielist !== null && movielist.length > 0) ? movielist.map(movieData => (
            <table className="table table-stripped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Release Year</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Credits</th>
                        <th>Poster</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr key={movieData.id}>
                        <td>{movieData.titleNameText}</td>
                        <td>{movieData.titleReleaseText}</td>
                        <td>{movieData.titleTypeText}</td>
                        <td>
                            <ul>{movieData.topCredits.map(credit => (
                                <li>{credit}</li>
                            ))}</ul>
                        </td>                       
                        <td>{ (movieData["titlePosterImageModel"] !== undefined) ? <img src={movieData.titlePosterImageModel.url} height="290px" width="300px" alt={movieData.titlePosterImageModel.caption} /> :  <img src="" height="290px" width="300px" alt={movieData.titleNameText} /> }</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>            
        )) : null;  
    };  

    const reducerFn = (state, action) => {

        if(action.type === "SET_MOVIE"){            
            return {
                ...state, 
                "movieQuery" : action.searchQuery
            };
        }

        if(action.type === "SEARCH_MOVIE"){
            let payload = [];           
            
            MovieAPI.getMovieList(action.searchQuery)
                    .then((data) => {
                        console.log(data);
                        
                        if ("results" in data["titleResults"]){
                            payload = data["titleResults"]["results"];
                            dispatchFn({
                                "type" : "LOAD_MOVIE_LIST",
                                "payload" : payload
                            });
                        }
                    
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });

            return {
                ...state,
                "movieList" : [],
                "movieListComponent" : createMovieListComponent(undefined, true)
            };
        }

        if(action.type === "LOAD_MOVIE_LIST"){          
            return {
                ...state,
                "movieList" : action.payload,
                "movieListComponent" : createMovieListComponent(action.payload, false)                              
            }
        }

        if(action.type === "MOVIE_RESET"){                      
            return {
                ...state, 
                "movieQuery" : "",
                "movieList" : [],
                "movieListComponent" : createMovieListComponent(undefined, false)
            }
        }
    }


    const [state, dispatchFn] = useReducer(reducerFn, initialObjectVal);
    
    return(
        <Fragment>
            <form className="form-horizontal">
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label for="inputmovie" className="col-sm-2 control-label">Search</label>
                    <div className="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="inputmovie" placeholder="search" value={state.movieQuery} onChange={event => {
                            dispatchFn({ 
                                "type" : "SET_MOVIE", 
                                "searchQuery" : event.target.value
                            });                                 
                        }} />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() =>{                       
                            dispatchFn({ 
                                "type" : "SEARCH_MOVIE", 
                                "searchQuery" : state.movieQuery
                            }); 
                        }}>Enter</button>&nbsp;
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" onClick={() => {
                            dispatchFn({ 
                                "type" : "MOVIE_RESET", 
                                "searchQuery" : ""
                            });
                        }}>Reset</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <hr/>
            {state.movieListComponent}
        </Fragment>
    );
}

The movieAPI.js
'use strict';

const requestSetting = {
    "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "imdb146.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "some_key"
    }
}

const getMovieList = (movieName) => {
    console.log("Movie to be searched "+movieName);
    const url = "https://imdb146.p.rapidapi.com/v1/find/?query="+movieName;
    console.log("Movie url "+url);
    return getRequest(url);
}

const getRequest = (url) => {   
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            ...requestSetting,
            "url" : url,
            "type" : "GET",
            "success" : function(data){
                resolve(data);
            },
            "error" : function(xhr, status, error){
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    }); 
}

export default {
    "getMovieList" : getMovieList
}

Can you please do a code review and suggest any improvements?
